# JavaScript - variable change but the if don't apply

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

```
'use strict'
let turn =0;
function addx(id){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<p>x</p>';
    turn = 0;
}
function addo(id){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<p>o</p>';
    turn = 1;
}
if(turn==1){
    document.getElementById('leftTop').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('leftTop')});
    document.getElementById('centerTop').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('centerTop')});
    document.getElementById('rightTop').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('rightTop')});
    document.getElementById('leftCenter').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('leftCenter')});
    document.getElementById('centerCenter').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('centerCenter')});
    document.getElementById('rightCenter').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('rightCenter')});
    document.getElementById('leftBottom').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('leftBottom')});
    document.getElementById('centerBottom').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('centerBottom')});
    document.getElementById('rightBottom').addEventListener("click",function (){addx('rightBottom')});
}
else{
    document.getElementById('leftTop').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('leftTop')});
    document.getElementById('centerTop').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('centerTop')});
    document.getElementById('rightTop').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('rightTop')});
    document.getElementById('leftCenter').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('leftCenter')});
    document.getElementById('centerCenter').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('centerCenter')});
    document.getElementById('rightCenter').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('rightCenter')});
    document.getElementById('leftBottom').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('leftBottom')});
    document.getElementById('centerBottom').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('centerBottom')});
    document.getElementById('rightBottom').addEventListener("click",function (){addo('rightBottom')});
}
```

i try tic tac toe game, i want to one turn x and after o, and it not change and print only x or only o if i declare the 'turn' otherwise. when i console i can see the turn value is changed but it still print the function of the turn is declared in the beginning of the js.

Comment: how is the code in the question called again when `turn` changes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The lines of code written is not being executed when the `turn` value is changed.

```js
'use strict'
let turn = 0;
function addx(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<p>x</p>';
  turn = 0;
  pleaseCallMe();
}
function addo(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '<p>o</p>';
  turn = 1;
  pleaseCallMe();
}
function pleaseCallMe() {
  if (turn == 1) {
    document.getElementById('leftTop').addEventListener("click", function () { addx('leftTop') });
    document.getElementById('centerTop').addEventListener("click", function () { addx('centerTop') });
    document.getElementById('rightTop').addEventListener("click", function () { addx('rightTop') });
    document.getElementById('leftCenter').addEventListener("click", function () { addx('leftCenter') });
    document.getElementById('centerCenter').addEventListener("click", function () { addx('centerCenter') });
    document.getElementById('rightCenter').addEventListener("click", function () { addx('rightCenter') });
    document.getElementById('leftBottom').addEventListener("click", function () { addx('leftBottom') });
    document.getElementById('centerBottom').addEventListener("click", function () { addx('centerBottom') });
    document.getElementById('rightBottom').addEventListener("click", function () { addx('rightBottom') });
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('leftTop').addEventListener("click", function () { addo('leftTop') });
    document.getElementById('centerTop').addEventListener("click", function () { addo('centerTop') });
    document.getElementById('rightTop').addEventListener("click", function () { addo('rightTop') });
    document.getElementById('leftCenter').addEventListener("click", function () { addo('leftCenter') });
    document.getElementById('centerCenter').addEventListener("click", function () { addo('centerCenter') });
    document.getElementById('rightCenter').addEventListener("click", function () { addo('rightCenter') });
    document.getElementById('leftBottom').addEventListener("click", function () { addo('leftBottom') });
    document.getElementById('centerBottom').addEventListener("click", function () { addo('centerBottom') });
    document.getElementById('rightBottom').addEventListener("click", function () { addo('rightBottom') });
  }
}
pleaseCallMe();
```